# java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write to /storage/emulated/0/Download/

Tags: kotlin, android-download-manager

I have an application where i need to get url from edittext and then download manager to downlaod the file , but something is wrong that keeps crashing the app , i tried granting permissions but even after granting permission , it keeps crashing , i would appreciate any help guys , thank you.

- This is the error

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write to /storage/emulated/0/Download/
```

- This is my code

```
   binding.download.setOnClickListener {
           if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
             if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

             } else {
                 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
             }
           } else {
              downloadFile()
           }
        }
    }

    private fun downloadFile() {
        val downloadUrl = binding.editUrl.text.toString()
        val downloadRequest = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadUrl))
        downloadRequest.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
        downloadRequest.setTitle("Download")
        downloadRequest.setDescription("Download Simple File..")
        downloadRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
        downloadRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_ONLY_COMPLETION)
        downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS , "" + System.currentTimeMillis())

        val downloadManager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        downloadManager.enqueue(downloadRequest)


    }
```

- This is after granting permissions

```
  override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode == READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE &&  grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                downloadFile()
        }
    }
```

Comment: have u solved this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

As the title says. You want to write but requesting only read permission.

You need to request `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: I have done that as well but i just didn't include the manifest file code , i have added the write permission to my app , when i start the app , it shows the dialog and  i grant the permission , as soon as i grant the permission , it crashes and shows me the above message